# One of two mutually exclusive fields should be visible docuSignApi

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to figure out if DocuSign support cross conditional fields.

For example, there are two check boxes (chk1 and chk2), both are optional and visible at start. 
Once user selects either of them, the other checkbox should be disabled/hidden.

But user can unselect first check box and again both check boxes are available for selection. And then user can again either select Chk1 or Chk2 and other checkbox will be disabled / hidden.

I tried all possible combinations of conditional field and values but it makes both check boxes invisible once I select any the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible as it would create a conditional loop.

Ideally you would want to control other fields in the document using checkboxes rather than each other.